# How do I return valid data from ajax call to DataTables child table?

Tags: datatables, parent-child

I am returning data in json format from an ajax call to populate a child table that sits below the parent table. I get the following "DataTables warning: table id=child - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0, column 1. For more information about this error, please see [http://datatables.net/tn/4"](http://datatables.net/tn/4%22). I have read the suggested information but unfortunately cannot relate it to my data. Any pointers in the right direction would be great please. The relevant code is:-

```
    jQuery('#parent tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
      
      var drno = (parentTable.row( this ).data()[4]);
      
      jQuery.get("ajaxchild.php", {drno: drno}, function(data){ 
        
        dataset = data;
        //console.log(dataset) returns
/*      
        [["INV1","","2014-06-03","18.00","2.70"],["CRN6","","2014-10-20","6.00","0.90"],["REC4","","2014-06-20","13.80","0.00"],["REC5","","2014-10-24","5.00","0.00"],["P_C1","","2014-10-24","5.00","0.00"],["INV24","","2014-11-21","109.86","16.48"],["REC29","","2014-11-29","100.00","0.00"],["INV30","","2014-12-04","21.75","3.26"],["REC30","","2014-12-04","25.01","0.00"],["CRN23","","2014-12-04","21.75","3.26"],["REC34","","2014-12-20","1.16","0.17"],["REC40","","2015-01-30","200.00","0.00"],["REC44","","2017-02-15","5.00","0.00"],["REC45","","2017-02-15","10.00","0.00"]]
*/                                                       
        var childTable = $('#child').DataTable( {
            data: dataset,                                     
            columns: [
                { "title": "Reference" },
                { "title": "Our Ref." },
                { "title": "Date" },
                { "title": "Value" },
                { "title": "Tax" }
            ]                                
                                               
        })
      });
 
    }); 

        // Reload the child table when selecting parent row
        // This will load the child table with the corresponding data
        parentTable.on( 'select', function () {
            childTable.ajax.reload();
         
        } );
        
        // Reload the child table when deselecting row
        // The child script should return zero 
        // records to clear the table
        parentTable.on( 'deselect', function () {
            childTable.ajax.reload();
        } );
```

Many thanks
Murray